# Integrated security=false vs omitted

Tags: sql-server, database, connection-string, ado, integrated-security

I'm using ADO to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database.  I'm using an OLE DB connection.  Connection string looks like:  `PROVIDER=sqloledb;DATA SOURCE=lokdb;USER ID=secret;PASSWORD=secret;APP=LokEng_Tests;WSID=LOKSPEC1;NETWORK LIBRARY=dbmssocn;INITIAL CATALOG="edms-lok";Persist Security Info=False;INTEGRATED SECURITY=false;`

(I also tried `INTEGRATED SECURITY=no`)

This throws an error when I try to open the connection, however if I omit the `INTEGRATED SECURITY` argument it then works.

I'm fine with omitting the argument if that's what I need to do, just wondering why that works when explicitly setting the argument to FALSE or NO causes an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx) states:

> Accepts the value "SSPI" for Windows Authentication.

So there is only one valid value: `SSPI`. If you don't want to use it simply omit it.